# How to stop blender from showing me the entire wireframe in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, wireframe

[image]

I’m working in edit mode, and I’m trying to use the wireframe of a different object as a reference. However, whenever I move my cursor, blender shows me an X-ray of the entire wireframe. I have X-ray mode turned off, but I turned on the wireframe visibility in “show displays”. Thank you for reading

Comment: Hard to tell from the screenshot... I can achieve the same look, but I cannot tell from what I see if that is the same in your scene: When the blue object is slightly inside the yellow object, the yellow faces are flipped and _Backface Culling_ is enabled - then I see the same result. But this is not dependent on moving the cursor, it is permanent. Maybe you could upload your file for investigation: https://blend-exchange.com